# how to make pong ball movements

Tags: javascript, html, css, game-physics, pong

This is my html:

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset ="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Pong</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pong.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="mainCanvas" width="700" height="710"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="pong.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css:

```
#mainCanvas{
    width: 700px;
    height: 710px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

This is my js:

```
//variables

var canvas = document.getElementById('mainCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var keys = [];

var speed = 12,
    playerWidth = 8,
    playerHeight = 75,
    canvasW = 700,
    canvasH = 710,
    player1X = canvasW - 670,
    player2X = canvasW - 30,
    ballS = 15,
    running = true,
    acc = 0,
    ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);

var requestAnimFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

//objects

function player(x,y,width,height){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

function gameObj(x,y,vel,side,speed){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.side = side;
    this.speed = speed;
}

var player1 = new player(player1X,canvasH/2-playerHeight/2,playerWidth,playerHeight);
var player2 = new player(player2X,canvasH/2-playerHeight/2,playerWidth,playerHeight);

var ball = new gameObj(canvasW/2-ballS/2,canvasH/2-ballS/2,ballS,15);

//Events

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    delete keys[e.keyCode];
}, false);

/*  
    keys
    up-38
    down-40

*/

//functions

function game(){
    update();
    render();
}

function update(){
    if(keys[38])player1.y -=speed;
    if(keys[40])player1.y +=speed;
    if(keys[87])player2.y -=speed;
    if(keys[83])player2.y +=speed;

    if(player1.y <0) player1.y=0;
    if(player1.y >= canvasH - player1.height) player1.y = canvasH - player1.height;

    if(player2.y <0) player2.y=0;
    if(player2.y >= canvasH - player2.height) player2.y = canvasH - player2.height;
    console.log("player1.y: " + player1.y);
    console.log("player2.y: " + player2.y);
}
function render(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasW,canvasH);
    ctx.fillStyle="white";
    ctx.fillRect(player1.x, player1.y, player1.width, player1.height);
    ctx.fillStyle="white";

    ctx.fillRect(player2.x, player2.y, player2.width, player2.height);
    ctx.fillStyle="white";

    ctx.fillRect(canvasW/2-3, 0, 3, canvasH);
    ctx.fillStyle="white";
    ctx.fillStyle="red";
    ctx.fillRect(ball.x,ball.y,ball.side,ball.side);
}

function animate() {
    if (running) {
         game();
    }
    requestAnimFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

I am having some trouble making the ball move in my pong game.  I don't have much experience. I know you can do `ball.x += ball.speed` but I'm not sure how to make it bounce of the walls and paddles. I tried to make it so when the ball collides with a paddle it equals it's x and y values but then the ball follows the paddle around.  When I try to change the direction by making the speed opposite of what it was a collision, the ball just stays still when it collides. Please help.

Any help at all is welcome.

Sorry if my code is a little sloppy, I am not formally trained.

Comment: Maybe put this in a **snippet**? 7:th icon from left in the editor :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic *pong*-movement. Hope it can give you some help. If you want someone to correct your code you might put it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)? One key part with this movement is to have more variables than one might think at first. Eg. is this code it is neeeded to have `box1Left1` *and* `box1Left2`.

```js
var box1Left1 = 0; 
var box1Left2;

setInterval(box1Fly, 10); 
function box1Fly() {
  // Fly Right
  if ( box1Left1 < 300 ) {
    box1Left1++; 
    document.getElementById("box1").style.left = box1Left1 + "px"; 
    box1Left2 = box1Left1;
  }
  // Fly Left
  if ( box1Left1 >= (300) ) {
    box1Left2--; 
    document.getElementById("box1").style.left = box1Left2 + "px"; 
  }
  // Fly Right Again
  if( box1Left2 == 0 ) { box1Left1 = box1Left2; }
  
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" style="position:absolute; top: 10px; left: 0px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: #aa39fc;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the ball is at `(ball.x, ball.y)` and moving at `(speed.x speed.y)`, in normal motion it moves to `(ball.x + speed.x, ball.y + speed.y)`. Do this then test for collisions to adjust for position and speed: speed on the colliding direction should be flipped to the opposite of what it was, and position should also be adjusted to its mirror image relative to the colliding wall or paddle, so that your ball doesn't render out of bounds.
If it collides with the left paddle i.e. `ball.x < 0`, `speed.x` becomes the opposite of what it was and so does `ball.x`.
If it collides with the right paddle i.e. `ball.x >= width`, `speed.x` becomes the opposite of what it was and `ball.x = width - (ball.x - width)` or `2*width - ball.x`
If it collides with the bottom wall i.e. `ball.y < 0`, `speed.y` becomes the opposite of what it was and so does `ball.y`.
If it collides with the top wall i.e. `ball.y >= height` then `speed.y` becomes the opposite of what it was and `ball.y = 2*height - ball.y`.
It's also possible for the ball to end up in a corner and collide with two walls within a single frame. Therefore process the x collisions then the y collisions--don't just think that because there's just been an x collision there isn't going to be a y collision.
For extra fun add a little bit of random motion to the speed components after a bounce on a paddle.